# Select and deselect multiple Items in flatlist performance issue

Tags: react-native, expo

Displaying more than 200+ images in the flatlist and make the user to select or deselect by clicking an image. So, when the user is clicks a image, Need to show the check-circle icon on the image. Similarly, when the user is deselect the selected image, need to remove the icon. I got two arrays **images[]** and **selectedImagesId[]**. Whenever the user selects an image, the image id will be pushed into selectedImagesId array. By the way, Iam showing the icon if the rendered image id avaliable in the selectedImagesId. The problem here is, it takes so long to display or remove the icon.

```
 <FlatList
 data={props.images}
 extraData={selectedImagesId}
 initialNumToRender={10}
 refreshing={true}
 removeClippedSubviews={true}
 maxToRenderPerBatch={1}
 windowSize={7}
 showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
 numColumns={3}
 keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}
 renderItem={(itemData) => <RenderData itemData={itemData} />}
 >


const RenderData = ({ itemData }) => (
    <View>
      <TouchableOpacity
        activeOpacity={0.8}
        style={{
          width: width / 3.5,
          height: height / 7,
          padding: 2,
        }}
        onPress={() => {
          console.log('pressed');
          if (props.selectedImages.includes(itemData.item.uri)) {
            const index = props.selectedImages.indexOf(itemData.item.uri);
            if (index > -1) {
              props.removeImageandId(index, itemData.item.id);
            }
          } else {
            props.selectImageandId(itemData.item.uri, itemData.item.id);
          }
        }}>
        <Image
          style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%' }}
          source={{
            uri: itemData.item.uri,
          }}
        />

        {selectedImagesId.includes(itemData.item.id) && (
          <AntDesign
            name='checkcircle'
            size={24}
            color='white'
            style={{ position: 'absolute', bottom: 5, right: 15 }}
          />
        )}
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <Text style={{ backgroundColor: 'red', fontSize: 25 }}>
        {render.current++}
      </Text>
    </View>
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Refer [This article](https://medium.com/game-development-stuff/how-to-avoid-rendering-non-changing-items-on-react-native-flatlists-9b4347d25ff3)

It will guide you on how to render Only particular selected components that change.
not the Whole flatList components.

so, that based Only selected particular component you can remove the icon. not whole flatList Re-render.